# Killing a Windows 7 program using Python 2.7x

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, tor, psutil

I currently have the below code:

```
 processlist = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            process = psutil.Process(p.pid)
            pname = process.name()
            processlist.append(pname)
        except:
            pass
    if "tor.exe" in processlist:
        os.system("Taskkill /im tor.exe")
    process = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In essence,I want the Python code to kill the Tor Browser if it is open and to then reopen it. Nonetheless, when I run this code, the Tor browser displays a message stating that there is an error with the Browser and would the user like to close and restart the browser? I don't really want this to happen and so I'm just wondering if there is another way of closing the browser avoiding this confirmation prompt message?

Answer (score 0):

Type `taskkill /?`

All you are doing is asking Tor (whatever that is) to close, ie send a `WM_Close` message. `/f` terminates an application.

Comment: Also your language can call WMI. So you can kill `tor` direct in your code. The command line equiv is `wmic process where "Name='notepad.exe'" call terminate 0` or in vbs `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2"):Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process"):For Each objItem in colItems:msgbox objItem.name:next`

Comment: Also there is an API call **TerminateProcess** 

Terminates the specified process and all of its threads.


`BOOL WINAPI TerminateProcess(
  HANDLE hProcess,
  UINT uExitCode
);

`